# Execute terminal commands using python gtk

Tags: terminal, python, gtk3

I want to make a quick app using gtk and python that when a button is clicked it executes a terminal command. Anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [this tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for Python and Gtk. The [second example](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#extended-example) in the tutorial shows how to create a window with a button so to run a command you just need to change the `on_button_clicked` callback. You can use either `os.system` or the `subprocess` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run commands with Python.

So to run `ls` for example:

```
import subprocess
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        subprocess.run(["ls"])


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```